# Move files from Sharepoint 2007 to Sharepoint 2013 and retain version history and modified date

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, version-history, content-migration

We are creating a new sharepoint site in Sharepoint 2013 and migrating content from the old site with Sharepoint 2007. The problem is we need to retain version history for files and also modified date. Is there any method how to do it?

Comment: you can use powershell script by writing the systemupdate() method for the list items for achieving this functionality.

Comment: @SaMolPP Can you explain detail on it? Because I am quite new in Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

write a powershellscript that Iterate throuh your site collection and all the spweb objects and all the document libs and splists , announcements , issue tracer lists , discussion forums etc like objects and fetch all the docs having versions 
and insert into the target 2013 site collection objects.

you first need to create the similar structure in the sp 2013 site collec. when compared to your MOSS 2007 site.

you didnt tell anything about any other details about your environment, this is required , as yours is a migration project.
then run the powershell script for the same.

if your customer is ready to buy 3rd party tools , the go for metalogix or sharegate kind of tools that will help you to ease your pain in migration.
 usually  migration is a painful activity. 
Share-Gate has 15 days trial, so try it.

Another approach is ,  take the content db backup from SQL server and migrate it to a SP 2010 content database and then from SP 2010 content db to SP 2013 content database. you need  to use SQL SERVER 2012 for the SP 2013 environment.

Comment: @SaMoIpp This must done in server?

Comment: Executing PowerShell from a remote machine  requires a lot of steps. so its good to run the powershell scripts within the server itself. Login to the server and open powershell ISE --> run as admin and add the                   add-pssnapin and write the scripts below that line of code. also  iam unclear about your env details whether you have permissions on both server or, do you have 2010 license , do you have sp 2013 +sql server correct version of s/w etc etc.unless you elaborate i cant give a perfect answer for your requirement, since it involves migration activity.